# How to receive continuous stream of states from two publishers working together

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a function `getState()`, the purpose of which is to return a continuous stream of `States`. I have two publishers: `statePublisher` and `requestPipeline`.

When I call `getState()`, the `requestPipeline` is sent a `Request`. As the pipeline progresses, it returns states to the `statePublisher`.

This `statePublisher` gets referenced strongly during the operator `.doThingThree(statePublisher)`. This operator presents a View Controller which holds on to the `statePublisher`. When that view controller dismisses, it sends a `State` and then completes.

This is my current, broken, code:

```
func getState(request: Request) -> AnyPublisher<State, Never> {
  let statePublisher = PassthroughSubject<State, Never>()
  let requestPipeline = PassthroughSubject<Request, Error>()

  requestPublisher = requestPipeline
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .doThingOne()
    .doThingTwo(statePublisher)
    .doThingThree(statePublisher)


  requestPipeline.send(request)


  return statePublisher
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func getMyState() {
  cancellable = getState(request: myRequest)
    .sink { state in
      print(state) // Never gets fired
    }
}
```

Unfortunately calling `getMyState()` doesn't do anything. Do I need to subscribe to the `requestPublisher` before I can do anything? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to subscribe to a `PassthroughSubject` before you send any values through it in order to receive events.

In your code you call `getState`.

`getState` calls `send`.

The `send` is ignored because there are no subscribers to `requestPipeline`.

Then `getState` returns.

You then you subscribe to `statePublisher` with `sink`.

Your code doesn't show any values ever being sent to `statePublisher`.

If there are were events being sent in `doThingTwo` and `doThingThree` then they are sent long before `sink` subscribes to `statePublisher`.

But then again `doThingTwo` and `doThingThree` are never invoked in the code that you've shown because there are no subscribers to `requestPublisher` or `requestPipeline`

If you are unsure if your publishers are executing use the `.print(<name>)` operator to see subscriptions and values passing through the pipeline.

Comment: `requestPipeline` is stored in `requestPublisher`, which is not locally scoped though

Comment: Removed the comment about the scoping of requestPipeline and enhanced the part that is really the cause of your problem.